# ¿Que significa en sass/scss "&"?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Me he encontrado con esto en un fichero de `sass/scss` de [Bootstrap v4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_nav.scss#L79):

```
.nav-pills {
  .nav-link {
    @include border-radius($nav-pills-border-radius);

    &.active,
    .show > & { /* <-- !!! */

      color: $nav-pills-link-active-color;
      background-color: $nav-pills-link-active-bg;
    }
  }
}
```

Se que normalmente se refiere `&` al selector padre (directo):

```
.clasePadre {

  &.claseHijo {

  }
}
```

Equivale a `.clasePadre.claseHijo`.

¿Entonces sería en este caso `.show > &` equivalente a `.show > .nav-pills .nav-link`?

Es decir: ¿Se hereda todas los selectores padres con `&`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Entonces sería en este caso `.show > &` equivalente a `.show > .nav-pills .nav-link?`

**Sí**.

> ¿Se hereda todas los selectores padres con `&`?

**Sí**.

Según la [documentación oficial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector) (Inglés):

> Sometimes it's useful to use a nested rule's parent selector in other
>   ways than the default. For instance, you might want to have special
>   styles for when that selector is hovered over or for when the body
>   element has a certain class. In these cases, you can explicitly
>   specify where the parent selector should be inserted using the &
>   character.

Traducción de [librosweb.es](http://librosweb.es/libro/sass/capitulo_4.html#referenciando_a_los_selectores_padre):

> En ocasiones es necesario modificar el comportamiento por defecto de
>   los selectores anidados. Imagina que quieres aplicar estilos
>   especiales en el estado `hover` del selector o cuando el elemento
>   `<body>` de la página tiene una determinada clase.
>   En estos casos, puedes utilizar el carácter `&` para hacer referencia
>   al selector padre dentro del cual se encuentra la regla anidada.

Ejemplo `sass/scss`:

```
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
  body.firefox & { font-weight: normal; }
}
```

El código `sass/scss` anterior se compila de la siguiente manera:

```
a { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
body.firefox a { font-weight: normal; }
```

El carácter especial `&` siempre se reemplaza por el selector padre tal y como aparece en el archivo `CSS`. Esto significa que si tiene una regla anidada, primero se calcula el selector padre completo y después se reemplaza por `&`.

Ejemplo `sass/scss`:

```
#main {
  color: black;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover { color: red; }
  }
}
```

Se compila en `CSS`:

```
#main { color: black; }
#main a { font-weight: bold; }
#main a:hover { color: red; }
```